# Show Separate Mark Labels alongside Measure Value Labels

Tags: tableau-api

[image: cimage]
<sub>(source: [tableau.com](https://community.tableau.com/servlet/JiveServlet/downloadImage/2-512229-149596/736-456/pastedImage_1.png))</sub>

I'm using Measure Values for combining two measures:

1)Count of Clients (As a percentage)

2)% Retention (Calculated field which uses another calculated field called Numerator Retention in it's formula over the total to calculate the %)

Measure Value Mark Labels successfully show the respective percentages for the two measures. Now I wanna show the respective count of clients or numbers behind these percentages but I'm unable to do so since I've already used Measure Value Mark Labels to do something similar.

When I try editing the Labels text, it edits it for all labels together and hence I'm getting all labels for all rows and not how I want it to show selectively as I described.

**Example Solution:** For Private Residence, I only want 125 to show with 60% which is the actual number behind the percentage. And I want only 119 to show with 95%

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this, but not using `Measure Values`. You should mirror what I have done here. I do not know your calculation for the `Respective Retention`, so use your calculation.

[image]

---

You need to move both of your measures to the `Columns` shelf and make them a `Dual Axis`:

[image]

After doing that, you will have access to the individual measures - so you can give labels independently:

[image]

Just make sure you place the measures that you want for each axis respectively.